# Hide NativeExpressAdView when soft keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a layout for my app that has a NativeExpressAdView on the bottom and a FloatingActionButton right above it.

When the user clicks on an EditText that triggers the soft keyboard, the NativeExpressAdView along with the FloatingActionButton comes up.

I want to leave the NativeExpressAdView behind the keyboard and only brings the FloatingActionButton up.

Check the screenshots:

Soft keyboard not visible:
[image: Soft keyboard not visible]

Soft keyboard is visible:
[image]

Comment: I guess you have to do it manually by writing these lines when your keyboard shown up (and do the opposite when it goes away): `nativeExpressAdView.pause();` and `nativeExpressAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`